# Can I use for loop in verilog `define statement?

Tags: loops, for-loop, macros, verilog, definition

I need to include a rather complex computation in a verilog macro. Can I use for loop in Macro definition? Below is given the example of my code

```
`define CLOGB2(depth) \

      integer width \

      for(width=0;depth>0;width=width+1) \
        depth = depth >> 1; \

      return width


 module test #(parameter MEMDEPTH = 16)

         (
           // Input-output port declaration
         );

parameter MEMWIDTH = `CLOGB2(MEMDEPTH);

$display("Calculated width : %d\n",MEMWIDTH);

...

...

endmodule
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is largely a duplicate of [How-to-define-a-multi-line-macro-in-verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483990/how-to-define-a-multi-line-macro-in-verilog).

The reason for using the multi-line define or task in this question appears to be for a ceiling log2 function which is available by other means.

### SystemVerilog & Verilog-2005

A built in `$clog2()` function is available

### Verilog

Including you own function if `$clog2` is not available may be simpler:

```
function integer CLog2;
  input   [31:0] depth;
  integer i;
  begin
    i = depth;
    for(CLog2 = 0; i > 0; CLog2 = CLog2 + 1)
      i = i >> 1;
  end
endfunction
```